# Setup enrolments in Moodle 2.x

Tags: moodle

An Enrol Plugin in Moodle 1.9x could have a `setup_enrolments(&$user)` method to set user enrolments. This method was called by the lib when user log in.

Does Moodle 2.x uses a similar method?

I couldn't find any call to `setup_enrolments()` method. Must it have another name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I believe enrol_plugin::sync_user_enrolments() does it. From [lib/enrollib.php](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/lib/enrollib.php#L1473):

```
/**
 * Forces synchronisation of user enrolments.
 *
 * This is important especially for external enrol plugins,
 * this function is called for all enabled enrol plugins
 * right after every user login.
 *
 * @param object $user user record
 * @return void
 */
public function sync_user_enrolments($user) {
    // override if necessary
}
```